# WSO2 Update swagger published API

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am trying to update the swagger of an published APi with this curl:

```
curl -X POST -b cookies "http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag" -d 'action=updateAPI&name=datumvalidatie&provider=admin&version=1.0.0&visibility=public&thumbUrl=&description=test&tags=validation&endpointType=nonsecured&tiersCollection=Gold,Bronze&http_checked=http&https_checked=https' -d 'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"https://www.test.com/datumvalidatieWebApi/api","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}' -d 'swagger={"basePath" : "/DatumvalidatieWebApi", "paths" : {"/perioden/ingangsdatum" : {"get": {"summary" : "test", "x-auth-type": "Application \u0026 Application User", "deprecated" : false, "produces" : ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"], "operationId" : "Ingangsdatum_Get", "responses" :  {"200": {"schema" : {"$ref": "#/definitions/Periode"}, "description": "OK"}, "400" : {"schema" : {"type": "array", "items" : {"$ref" : "#/definitions/Object"}}, "description" : "BadRequest"}},  "x-throttling-tier" : "Unlimited", "tags" : ["Ingangsdatum"], "consumes": []}}}, "host" : "*******", "schemes" : ["http"], "definitions" : {"Periode" : {"description" : "Een periode", "type" : "object", "properties" : {"DatumVan " : {"format" : "date-time", "type" : "string"}, "DatumTot" : {"format" : "date-time", "type" : "string"}}}, "Object" : {"type" : "object", "properties" : {}}}, "swagger" : "2.0", "info" : {"description" : "Een collectie methoden om datumvalidaties uit te voeren.", "title" : "datumvalidatie", "version" : "1.0.0"}}'
```

I get this respond:

```
"error" : true, "message" : "timeout"

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \u0026

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Application

curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 43

curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 38

curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 85

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: collectie

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: methoden

......
```

Does someone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've observed this error when I hadn't logged in before making a service call. Did you login before sending above curl request? If not, login first like this.

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

This is mentioned at the top of [REST API doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs).

Comment: Yes i logged in before i tried this.
I got a "error: false" message back from the login so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Hmm, in that case i maybe need to look at the connection settings for the AM. If i can find a solution myself i will post it here.

Thanks for your time.